# Merge Arrays when one value is >0 then return new array

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

I'm trying to merge two arrays into one (PHP), except in the new array I only want to display values from the combination of both arrays where $b > 0.

I've used `array_filter` to get the values where `$b > 0`, but now I need help combining the arrays together and returning a final array which I will then insert into a database.

For example `if $a = [0] => 351 [1] => 352 [2] => 353`

and `$b = [2] => 3 //array_filter has removed [0] => 0 [1] => 0`

I would want the new array ($c) to be [0] => 353,3 using the following code:

```
print_r($a = $_POST['price']); 
print_r($b = array_filter($_POST['qty']));

$count = count($a);
$i = 0;

while ($i < $count)
{
    $c = $a[$i] . "," . $b[$i]; 
    $i++;
}

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    print_r ($c);
}
```

However at present my result is this:

```
Array //$a
(
    [0] => 351
    [1] => 352
    [2] => 353
)
Array //$b
(
    [2] => 1
)
353,1353,1353,1 //$c
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
$a = array(351, 352, 353);
$b = array(2 => 3);

$c = array();
foreach($b as $key => $value)
{
    $c[] = $a[$key];
    $c[] = $b[$key]; 
}

print_r($c);
```

This will give you:

```
Array ( [0] => 353 [1] => 3 )
```

And if you want to have the array $c as comma seperated string use:

```
$c = implode(',', $c);
```

This will give you:

```
'353,3'
```

Comment: This works perfect thanks. However, when I then go to add the information into the database, the loop does not seem to work:

$d = array();
foreach($b as $key => $value)
{
    $d[] = $a[$key];
    $d[] = $b[$key]; 
 $d[] = $c[$key];  
 
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO basket (basket_id,session_id, plot_id,  product_type,product_id,qty,line_price) VALUES ('','".mysql_real_escape_string($session_id)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($plot_id)."','Furniture','".mysql_real_escape_string($d[2])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($d[1])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($d[0])."')");

}

Comment: It appears to only add the first item in $d to the database (the correct amount of times)

Comment: So you want in your database something like `'353,3'`?

Comment: If my array contains two values say 0 => 353,1 1 => 354,2 the database will enter 353,1 twice instead of 353,1 then 354,2

Comment: In your code you put your database query into the foreach loop. So every cycle you insert $d[0], $d[1] and $d[2]. So they are always the same. You have to rewrite this.

Comment: You could replace $d[0] with $a[$key] and so on. I dont see any use to create the d array if you want to safe it only into the database.

Comment: Solved with: 
$a = $_POST['price']; 
$b = array_filter($_POST['qty']);
$c = $_POST['furniture_id'];


foreach($b as $key => $value)
{
    
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO basket (basket_id,session_id, plot_id,  product_type,product_id,qty,line_price) VALUES ('','".mysql_real_escape_string($session_id)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($plot_id)."','Furniture','".mysql_real_escape_string($c[$key])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($b[$key])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($a[$key])."')");

}